# Moving a snap from one server to another

Tags: migration

I need to migrate nextcloud, which is running as a snap, from one server to another. Aside from changing CNAME and stuff like that, is there a simple process to make this transfer happen seamlessly?

Both servers have a snap of nextcloud running at the same version. One server is running Ubuntu 20.04, the other Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you **really** want is to migrate user accounts and their data from one instance of Nextcloud to another instance, then see https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/22/admin_manual/maintenance/migrating.html for the Nextcloud instructions on how to:

1. Put your servers into maintenance mode.
2. Dump the database from system #1.
3. Import the dump into system #2.
4. Copy data files from system #1 to system #2.

Trying to migrate the snap package is generally wasted effort. The snap is read-only. The snap contains no user accounts nor user data. Moving the snap to a different system will give you an empty Nextcloud install, with no users nor data.

- All user accounts and data are in the database and the data files. THAT's what needs to be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wishing there was a command to make the whole process a bit less tedious, you're in luck! The Nextcloud snap has a [built-in utility for performing migrations](https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap/wiki/How-to-backup-your-instance). The link is to their GitHub wiki, so it may move around. I found it by searching "nextcloud snap data backup."

The short version is: Run `sudo nextcloud.export`, which will generate a directory in `/var/snap/nextcloud/common/backups/`.

On the new server, run `sudo nextcloud.import <backupdir>` and it will replace your existing nextcloud install with the backup.

I did this by plugging my old hard drive in to my server and running `nextcloud.import` directly on the backup file, but your approach may be different. There were two caveats for me: First, my nextcloud was set up to put data on a different hard drive, but the script looks for it in the default location (without checking the configs). I used a symbolic link to make the data accessible at `/var/snap/nextcloud/current/data` as the script expects. Second, when restoring, data has to be in the snap confinement, so I used a bind mount to make the external hard drive accessible in the snap.

Hope that helps!